# "Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file" but I have added directory to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012

I think this is a weird problem. I will try to give as much detail as I can. I am attempting to import a header for a custom class in a Visual Studio 2012 test project using:

```
#include "detector.h"
```

And am getting the error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'detector.h': No such file or directory

I have included the complete path to the folder in which the header file is located under `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`.

The header file is pretty long, but basically just contains declarations for a class. The `detector.cpp` file contains the definitions for the class. The directory structure on my file system looks like:

```
project_directory/
  - test/
    - [my_test_project]
  - detector_directory/
    - detector.h
    - detector.cpp
  - other_component_directory/
    - other_component.h
    - other_component.cpp
  ...
```

I *am* able to `#include other_component.h` and write and execute tests for that class. I am actually able to include *three* other classes and write and execute tests for all three, but four classes (including `detector`) are giving me this same error.

The whole `project_directory/` is checked out from an SVN repository to which only I have contributed so far. I mention that in case there could be some weirdness happening with links or something created for the repo. I think this problem could have arisen after reverting the repo to a previous update, but am not certain if I only noticed it then instead.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ***could be some weirdness happening with links*** You probably have to check yourself on that one. Make sure `detector.h` exists in the folder you expect and make sure you can open it and read it in Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm I can open it and read it in VS just fine. I can add it to the project, although I think _that_ just references it rather than copying it in. How do I check that it exists as an actual file and not some virtual link or something in Windows? I know how on a *nix OS...

Comment: 1) Do you have only one project in your MSVC solution or several ones? You would need to add the include directories in each project. 2) During the compilation of which cpp file does the error occur? You can compile the cpp files separately to find that out and see if it's for all of them.

Comment: @oLen partial answer to your questions: I have only the one project in my solution. The intellisense or whatever they call it recognizes the problem before compilation and underlines the `#include` in red with the message "Error: cannot open source file 'detector.h'". The project uses the `stdafx.h` header, in which my `#include "detector.h"` statement is located. When this header is read is when compilation fails.

Comment: @Engineero What if you compile it without using `stdafx.h` ?

Comment: @oLen I honestly do not know how to not use that. It seems like the test project is looking for that header specifically by default, and not including it causes a different error. If I just move all my individual class's `#include` statements to the main test file I still get the same error for `detector.h`.

Comment: @Engineero This is a precompiled header and in my experience it causes more problems than it solves. You can disable it under the properties of your project, then "Configuration Properties\C/C++\Precompiled Headers".

Comment: @oLen between your discussion and the answer below I was able to figure it out. Turns out it was a question of which configuration I was running vs. setting options for.

Comment: @Engineero Glad to hear you could solve it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have included **the complete path to the header file** under Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

It should be a directory path where `detector.h` header is located, not a file path.

Check that you have set this option for the active solution configuration. Sometimes it set for `Debug`, but not for `Release` and `Release` configuration is not able to build in such case.

Comment: @Engineero At the top of Project property page you can see available configurations. Select configuration Debug, Release and platform you need to build and check that options, e.g. `Additional Include Directories` configured properly. Also check that path length for this directory is less than 256 symbols.

Comment: I added the folder in which `detector.h` is located, not the path to the file. I have fixed this in my problem statement. It looks like the problem came down to which configuration I was setting options for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I scratched my head for ~3 hours for a similar problem today. In my case, there were was a hierarchy of build files used to build the binaries. I had to include the directory for my header file (`detector.h` in your case) as a dependency in the directory and project level Makefile.

```
project_directory/
- **libraries.mk**
- test/
- [my_test_project]
  - detector_directory/
    - **build.mk**
    - detector.h
    - detector.cpp
  - other_component_directory/
    - other_component.h
    - other_component.cpp
```

I had to add the path to `build.mk` and `libraries.mk`.

HTH!